# Criando novos usuarios através de Shell Script

Tags: linux, script, shell, permissões, argumento

Estou tentando criar um *shell script* para adicionar novos usuários ao sistema GNU/Linux

Mas sem inserir comandos nativo como **adduser** ou **useradd** no script, seria algo na unha.

Estou com algo quase fino(pronto!), mas preciso partilha idéias sobre o que pode ser feito.

Se você já tentou, ou fez algo parecido, permita-me saber.

Comment: Olá Diego, tenta descrever melhor o que você quer fazer, é por isso que ta ganhando os negativos. Outra coisa, não precisa do pendente no titulo, aqui é só marcar a pergunta como respondida.

Comment: @Intruso o "pendente" não foi ele quem inseriu :) A pergunta realmente foi fechada como pendente, veja o box amarelo(ou clique em editar e veja o campo de titulo)

Comment: @DiegoHenrique [pendente] é automático do sistema, eu não negativei, mas fechei porque não entendi de começo o que exatamente não funciona e como deveria funcionar. Talvez nem você mesmo tenha entendido e por isso ficou pouco clara, mas vou tentar ler e testar

Comment: @Diego Henrique, consegue editar sua pergunta e adicionar o que tem ate agora?

Comment: Eu acredito que terá resposta sim, a proposito, melhore o titulo, deixe mais claro. ;)

Comment: Agora ficou mais claro sim. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Quem tiver rodando alguma distro GNU/Linux já pode experimentar, ou para aqueles que não a tem, use algum sistema plataforma linux LiveCD ou USB.

## Código

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# Por - Diego Henrique "<netcenter@globomail.com>" 
#
# (c) 2016 Programa - Adicionar novos usuários na base do sistema GNU/Linux
#

ADD_UID=0; ADD_GID=0

for X in `cat /etc/passwd | cut -d ':' -f3`;
do
if [ $X > $ADD_UID ]; then
  ADD_UID=$X
fi
done
ADD_UID=$(($ADD_UID + 1))

for Y in `cat /etc/group | cut -d ':' -f3`;
do
if [ $Y > $ADD_GID ]; then
  ADD_GID=$Y
fi
done

ADD_GID=$(($ADD_GID + 1))


if [ $(id -u) != "0" ]
then

echo -ne "Se você é usuário de um sistema Linux, há arquivos que podem ser bloqueados a você.\nNo caso de arquivos e processos ligados ao funcionamento do sistema, seu proprietário natural é o usuário root. Isso significa que só ele é que pode alterá-los." 
exit 0

elif [ -z $2 ]
then

echo "Use: $0 opções usuário"
exit 0

elif [ "$(cat /etc/passwd | grep -i $1 | wc -l)" = "1" ]
then

echo "Usuário '$1' e seu criador '$2' já existente. Tente outro novamente."
exit 0

fi

if [ $2 = "" ]
then

echo "Favor, coloque o seu nome verdadeiro para o usuário."

elif [ "$(cat /etc/passwd | grep -i $2 | wc -l)" = "2" ]
then
echo "Usuário '$2' já existente. Tente outro novamente."
exit 0
fi

echo "Inclusão de usuário '$1' em /etc/passwd"

echo "$1::$ADD_UID:$ADD_GID:$2:/home/$1:/bin/sh" >> /etc/passwd

sleep 1

echo "Inclusão de usuário '$1' em /etc/group"

echo "$1:x:$ADD_GID:$1" >> /etc/group

if [ ! -d "/home/$1" ]
then

echo "Inclusão de usuário '$1' em /home/$1"
mkdir /home/$1

else

echo "Falha na Inclusão de usuário '$1'. Verifique e tente manualmente."
exit 1

fi

# Alterar proprietário e grupo de arquivos - comandos chown e chgrp

chown -R $1 /home/$1

chgrp -R $1 /home/$1

sleep 1

echo "Pronto! Novo usuário criado com sucesso."
```

## Exemplo

```
# ./script.sh dhg diego henrique guilherme
```

## Explicação

> Este pequeno *script* recebe dois argumentos seguidos do nome de usuário a criar, o "*dhg*" foi usado para ilustrar o exemplo, juntamente com o nome verdadeiro do seu criador "*diego henrique guilherme*" formando assim um novo usuário sobre o sistema pinguin.

Veja como ficou:

- /etc/passwd

`dhl::502:128:diego henrique guilherme:/home/dhl:/bin/sh`

- /etc/group

`dhl:x:114:dhl`

***Importante!*** - *O conteúdo disponibilizado aqui é tão básico do que completo. Portanto, cabe a qualquer um que deseje utilizar do mesmo fazer devidas adaptações em conformidade ao seu desejo particular.*